# haproxy http check with a backup server shows 503 at main server down

Tags: haproxy, traffic-filtering

I have been trying to setup a forward with haproxy.

```
listen POC-2019-02-03
    bind 0.0.0.0:8083
    timeout connect  14000
    timeout client   180000
    timeout server   180000
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    option httpclose
    option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1
    http-check expect rstring "Welcome"
    server S-ONE 127.0.0.1:6001 check
    server S-TWO 127.0.0.1:6002 check backup
```

which normally will serve as follows when request to http://127.0.0.1:8083:

- Shows the content of **S-ONE**
- But when requesting as like normal production scenario, multiple requests, as soon as I turn down the S-ONE, it shows

> ## 503 Service Unavailable
>
> No server is available to
>   handle this request.

Then the second request served via **S-TWO**

- It continuously then served by **S-TWO**. After then I do start the **S-ONE** and obviously request still serves from **S-TWO**, which is ok for me.
- I turn down **S-TWO** then without showing any error, it serves by **S-ONE**, Which is cool. But I do not get the reverse one in this scenario.

Is there anything I have to tweak here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [fall](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#fall) and [inter](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#inter):

> **fall <count>**
>
> The "fall" parameter states that a server will be considered as dead after
>    consecutive unsuccessful health checks. This value defaults to 3 if
>   unspecified. See also the "check", "inter" and "rise" parameters.
>
> **inter <delay>**
>
> The "inter" parameter sets the interval between two consecutive health checks
>   to  milliseconds. If left unspecified, the delay defaults to 2000 ms.

I've never tried that exact scenario, but I suspect before it actually marks the host as down (and thus activating the backup(s)), it has nowhere else to route traffic to, so continues sending it to {{s-ONE}} until it's officially "down".

Comment: You are a life saver ! I have tested it, seems ok for now but I have added :

       server S-ONE 127.0.0.1:6001 check non-stick observe layer7 error-limit 1 fall 1 inter 500ms
       server S-TWO 127.0.0.1:6002 check non-stick observe layer7 error-limit 1 fall 1 inter 500ms backup